# “edit” TCP header in a incoming traffic

Tags: tcp

I have three set of servers which will involve for the current data flow.

Server A ----> Server B ---> Remote Server/Storage

I am downloading/push files from Server A to B, and then server B will forward those files to a Remote server. When forwarding the logs from server B to Remote server, I want to keep the original server's HOST IP unchanged, which means; I want to add the Server A's IP to the TCP header when passing to the Remote server from Server B.

As I found on the "server fault" forum, there is a possibility to use "netsed" to achieve my requirement. sorry, it's not that clear for me. Could you please help me with this?

Thanks in advance,
Luke.

Comment: What protocol are you using to download/push file? What protocol do you wish to use to forward those files to Remote Server? Why do you want to keep the HOST IP unchanged?

Comment: This is about linux syslogs. I want to transfer syslogs of Server A to a remote server via Server B. Remote server uses the syslogs for further analysis. Thats why I want to keep the HOST IP (Server A) unchanged. Syslog will transfer over TCP.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for clarifying. I'll partly answer by saying you cannot use netsed to alter this before delivery, the Remote Server gets the IP from the immutable (without breaking) IP layer, event an NAT on Server B won't help as this is an IP rewrite. Even if you have a SSH tunnel from Server B to Remote Server it would only see the IP from B.

You could set up some VPN between Server A and Remote Server which will result in the visibility of the VPN ip of Server A over the link. This is probably a lot of effort for not much reward.

I recommend following the path of getting Server B's syslog to remotely listen for syslog messages from Server A, and forward those to the Remote server. There's an old article [rsyslog reliable forwarding](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/tutorials/reliable_forwarding.html), but depending on what you are using your current syslog server might support it in some way.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Further to my explained requirement; Server B actually having two tasks. Manipulating syslog for one of its own application and forwarding "raw syslogs" to the remote server which are receiving from Server A. Thats why I want to rewrite the tcp header of the raw syslogs by its original IP.
Anyway I will try as you suggested using rsyslog and will update you.

Comment: ok. BTW there is no IP in the TCP header. I suspect the syslog messages will get their source IP pre-pending to the syslog messages when received/stored on Server B so forwarding them together with the local syslog traffic won't be a big deal. Looking forward to seeing a final solution.